# Apache Kafka Server Stops Automatically

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using apache kafka for one of project. Kafka server stops automatically after I kept it running for 1 day. Can anyone tell me which config property I need to modify?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: can you provide but both zookeeper.properties and server.properties

Comment: You should also provide your running script with zookeeper and server properties. You should also post if there is anything in the logs related to this issue.

Comment: is it running on nohup mode?